# Bad route and redirect loop on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new on rails, but I managed to create an application that take values from a form, make some calculations using javascript and create a string like

```
127.0.0.1:3000/var1/var2/var3/var4
```

and then redirect to that url.

Now, I want to take these variables and perform another calculation on server side, then store the result on database.

For now, I have my route.rb like this

```
root "mcc#form"
get "process/:var1/:var2/:var3/:var4" => "mcc#process"
```

and my controller mcc_controller.rb like

```
class MccController < ApplicationController
    def form
    end

    def process
        #redirect_to "127.0.0.1:3000/", :status => 302
    end
end
```

Now, I'm getting an error if a let like this

```
wrong number of arguments calling `process` (1 for 0)
```

even if I ask for 127.0.0.1/ ( that should give me form.html.erb view ), and if I comment the second line on routes.rb I still get that error.

Making another experiment, I commented the "process" method on mcc_controller.rb and let the second line on routes.rb without comment, the everything works, but obviously, the call to 127.0.0.1:3000/var1/var2/var3/var4 doesn't work anymore.

In the "process" method I have a redirect, that should return to the main page for another calculations. Then I write my "process" method as follow

```
class ArenaController < ApplicationController
    def form
    end

    def process(var)
        redirect_to "127.0.0.1:3000/", :status => 302
    end
end
```

I get a "redirect loop" even if I go to 127.0.0.1.

So, I don't understand why is that loop. "Process" method should be called only when I ask for 127.0.0.1/var1/var2/var3/var4 and not when I ask for the root route.

I hope I was clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved bad routing and loops. It seems that "process" is some kind of reserved word, so I changed it for "qrocess" and now it works. The best part is that the url is the same!
Also, in

```
class ArenaController < ApplicationController
    def form
    end

    def process(var)
        redirect_to "127.0.0.1:3000/", :status => 302
    end
end
```

I used process(var) for avoiding "wrong number of arguments", but it seems that it's not necessary now.